# Twilio sms not handling exception

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

My application sends an sms message when a user signs up. I'm trying to handle the exception if the number is invalid, and Twilio fails to send it. But when the message fails, it never seems to reach the catch in my try/catch clause.

```
try {
    $message = $twilio->messages
        ->create(
            "$user->phone", // to
            array("from" => "$siteNumber", "body" => "$message_text")
        );
} catch (TwilioException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

I've also tried the following catch conditions.

```
} catch (\Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}

catch (RestException $e) {
    return redirect()->back()->withFlashSuccess("Failed To Send Text");
}
```

Comment: “it never seems to reach the catch” Do you know for sure? Have you tried to set a debug breakpoint there or var_dump something directly from the catch-clause? The problem may also be the evaluation of the surrounding functions return value or that the methods called in the catch-clause do not return any useful values.

Comment: Try and catch all general exceptions without specifying a specific exception class … maybe it throws a different one than you expected?

Comment: Try `catch(\Exception $e) { return get_class($e); }` (to test things, and determine exactly which class is being used). This is almost certainly a namespace issue - virtually every bit of code in a Laravel install is in a namespace of some sort, so you're actually trying to catch something like `App\Http\Controllers\TwilioException` that will never occur. If `TwilioException` is the *correct* exception, you probably need a `use Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException;` at the top of the file.

Comment: catch(\Exception $e) { return get_class($e) solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change the catch exception

```
catch (\Exception $e) {
return $e->getMessage();
}
```

It's working for me